# modify wordpress plugin function in javascript

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I try to change the function in js file. It is working fine I replace code in plugin file.

So now I copy that file into child themes and add wp_dequeue_script and wp_enqueue_script function in function.php but it is not working.

May I know which part is wrong in this script.

Regards,
Alex

```
function custom_enqueue_js_scripts() {
    $path = get_template_directory_uri();
    // remove the yith quick view script to queue our hooked version
    wp_dequeue_script('wcfmvm-script-membership-registration');
    wp_enqueue_script('wcfmvm-script-membership-registration', $path . 
   '/wcfm/membership/assets/js/min/wcfmvm-script-membership-registration.js', '', '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_js_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have wrong is the following line  `$path = get_template_directory_uri();`, `get_template_directory_uri` is used when you are in the parent theme, to get the url path of the child theme you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` so your code will be as following

```php
function custom_enqueue_js_scripts() {
    $path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    // remove the yith quick view script to queue our hooked version
    wp_dequeue_script('wcfmvm-script-membership-registration');
    wp_enqueue_script('wcfmvm-script-membership-registration', $path . 
   '/wcfm/membership/assets/js/min/wcfmvm-script-membership-registration.js', '', '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_js_scripts');
```

Comment: Added priority and it is working add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_js_scripts', 100);